# Cron for sending emails after 3 days in django

Tags: django, cron

I dont have any knowledge about the cron. In my project once the task is assigned to employee email is sent to his mailid. If the employee does not complete the task within deadline I want to send the mail after every 3 days to complete the task. Can anyone give me I idea what I should do. The project is on my local environment, does it support or I should take server.

Answer (score 0):

[apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) would do the job

It would look like this

```
    bg_scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    bg_scheduler.add_job(send_email, 'interval', days=3)
    bg_scheduler.start()
```